# CSS html grid layout

Tags: css, layout, grid

I'm trying to create a grid like this:

[image: Grid]

- All items can vary in height
- The item with the most height defines the height of the row
- I don't want to wrap each row in a column div, if possible, to make my code cleaner.

What I have tried:

- Using floats, but this won't be possible because I would still have to clearfix each row

Thanks

Comment: Interesting questions, have you been able to solve it?

Comment: @SeifSayed Nope.

Comment: the only way I can think of solving this is by using Bulma.io, supports behaviour by using flexbox. Bootstrap also solves this problem, I'll try to dig deeper in their code and find a solution in native CSS

Comment: @SeifSayed Oke, cool I have never heard of Bulma.io it looks promising. Thanks for trying to help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create this layout using Flexbox. You just need to set `flex-wrap: wrap` on flex-container so flex-items break to new row and tallest item will set height of that row.

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.content > div {
  background: red;
  flex: 0 0 calc(33.33% - 20px);
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div style="height: 100px">Div</div>
  <div style="height: 150px">Div</div>
  <div style="height: 90px">Div</div>
  <div style="height: 80px">Div</div>
  <div style="height: 70px">Div</div>
  <div style="height: 120px">Div</div>
  <div style="height: 100px">Div</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve what you're looking for using CSS `columns-count`, `column-fill:auto;` and the variations of `break-inside`. See my code below for example:

```css
#row {
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-fill: auto; /* Firefox */
    column-fill: auto;
    
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

#row p { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
    page-break-inside: avoid; /* For Firefox. */
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; /* For Chrome & friends. */
    break-inside: avoid; /* For standard browsers like IE. :-) */
}
```

```html
<div id="row">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sit amet lacus lobortis, ornare tellus eu, placerat diam.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sit amet lacus lobortis, ornare tellus eu, placerat diam. Vestibulum ultricies ante lacus, non vehicula nulla pharetra sit amet.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
<div id="row">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sit amet lacus lobortis, ornare tellus eu, placerat diam.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sit amet lacus lobortis, ornare tellus eu, placerat diam. Vestibulum ultricies ante lacus, non vehicula nulla pharetra sit amet.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
```